# Why rsync keep sending the same files every time it's invoked, even though the files have the same checksum?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

I am attempting to use rsync from Mac version 2.6.9 to transfer a file to Ubuntu version 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1028-aws x86_64). However, every time I try, rsync shows the same file, even though the checksums are identical:

```
rsync -Lavhr --checksum --times --omit-dir-times --stats ...
```

Here are the checksums for the file on each system

> Checksum Mac
>
> 3183a201c3f78840986d1b7e024fa82037930097c2192cd6740bbbd7a59623cd
> /Users/btz1/Sites/models/CategoryModel.php
>
> Checksum on Ubuntu
>
> 3183a201c3f78840986d1b7e024fa82037930097c2192cd6740bbbd7a59623cd
> /home/ubuntu/models/CategoryModel.php

Interestingly, this problem does not occur when transferring the file to another server running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1092-aws x86_64).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the installed version of rsync on macOS 2.6.4.
After upgrading to Homebrew version 3.2.7, the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip them, just add `--ignore-existing`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will prevent copying (updating) files that have been changed on the source