# rsync copying same files over and over again on macOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, rsync

I've recently updated macOS to Sonoma from Monterey.  I noticed that when I used `rsync --av`, it would keep copying the same files over and over again, even when I just reran the same command.

It's as if `rsync` didn't even run at all. This is occurring when copying files from my MacBook Pro to a Samsung external drive (which is formatted exFAT). I haven't had this problem before in Monterey.  I've noticed though that if tried `rsync` for directories within the MacBook Pro, I don't have this problem.

Interestingly, when I tried different directories which have been synced before between the MacBook Pro and the external hard drive, it knows the files have already been copied.

Interestingly if I add `--size-only` then it does not copy the same files over again, so not sure why the time stamps are creating a problem.

Is this a Sonoma issue or something larger at work?

This is with `rsync` version 2.6.9.

Comment: macOS files are case insensitive. Could be sending the same files over and over again with different casing each time. Have you tried to Homebrew solution suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1774733/167207)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rsync: identical files (contents, size, timestamp) between source and destination are not being seen as identical](https://superuser.com/questions/1751241/rsync-identical-files-contents-size-timestamp-between-source-and-destinatio)

Comment: I just used homebrew to update `rsync` to version 3.2.7.  I still have the same problem with `rsync` copying files that were already copied.  I'm starting to think it's the exFAT format of the Samsung X5 external hard drive.  Though I'm not sure why I'm having this problem now (since I've upgraded to Sonoma) and not before (when I was using Monterey).

Comment: Since you've adopted '-v' for verbose output, maybe worth to check with couple more flags see if helps, '-t' (Timestamps) if the timestamps on the source and destination files are different, even if the files are otherwise identical, rsync will copy the file again; '-n' to do a dry run, which will show which files would be copied without actually copying them.